# Getting all indexes of matching elements in string array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have this string array:

```
string[] stringArray = { "fg v1", "ws v2", "sw v3", "sfd v2"  };
string value = "v2";
```

How to get back all indexes of all occurrences value in the array?

so for this example we should get an array of `int = [1,3]`
 preferable without looping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right. There is no method in the [`Array`-class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.113).aspx) or extension method in the [`Enumerable`-class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns all indexes for a given predicate. So here is one:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndexes<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            yield return index;
        }

        index++;
    }
}
```

Here is your sample:

```
string[] stringArray = { "fg v1", "ws v2", "sw v3", "sfd v2" };
string value = "v2";

int[] allIndexes = stringArray.FindIndexes(s => s.Contains(value)).ToArray();
```

It uses deferred execution, so you don't need to consume all indexes if you don't want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the LINQ `Where` extension method to filter, and `Select` to get the index:

```
int[] indexesMatched = stringArray.Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index }
                                  .Where(x => x.Value.Contains("v2"))
                                  .Select(x => x.Index)
                                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I had no clue that the `.Select()` method had an overload which supported index in the selector too: `Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector)`

Answer (score 2):

Linq approach

```
string[] stringArray = { "fg v1", "ws v2", "sw v3", "sfd v2" };
string value = "v2";

int[] result = stringArray.Select((x, i) => x.Contains(value) ? i : -1)
                          .Where(x => x != -1)
                          .ToArray();
```

Comment: You could use SelectMany instead of Select, and skip the Where.

Answer (score 1):

Same result with Select followed by Where:

```
var indexes = stringArray.Select((x,i) => x.Contains(searchStr)? i.ToString() : "")
                         .Where(x=> x!="" ).ToList();
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M5SfEM)